# htaccess url rewriting from request query to folder like and changing the php name

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

How can I do the following on the localhost which will be hosted later online:

I have this link:

`http://localhost/shops/shop.php?c=15`

I want to rewrite it to `http://localhost/shops/shop/15`

htaccess is(which is placed in `C:\wamp\www\shops folder`):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?RECIPES/(.*?)/?$ /single-product-details.php?=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?SHOP/(.*?)/?$ /shop.php?=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Please do share your tried htaccess rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?RECIPES/(.*?)/?$ /single-product-details.php?=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/?SHOP/(.*?)/?$ /shop.php?=$1 [L]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following Rules. Place your htaccess file along with shops folder(not inside it).

Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteBase /shops/
##External redirect to friendly url.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/shops/(shop)\.php\?c=(\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]
##Internal rewrite to actual url/files.
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/(.*)/? $1.php?c=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: It didn't work, still showing: http://localhost/iCook/shop.php?c=5

Comment: its turned on from apache to rewrite, I did clear cache as well

Comment: @AliElMenini, what is the url you are hitting?

Comment: @AliElMenini, ok so you want to redirect from `localhost/shops/shop.php?c=7` TO `localhost/shops/shop` in browser? Please confirm once.

Comment: I want localhost/shops/shop.php?c=7 to be like localhost/shops/shop/7

Comment: @AliElMenini, ok, I have updated rules now, could you please check now and let me know how it goes? Make sure to clear your cache before testing URLs.

Comment: Nothing changed, just some of css files aren't loading - the whole design went down

Comment: @AliElMenini, I have edited my rules a bit please check them again and let me know how it goes. Also let me know where is your htaccess placed? With complete path and where is your shop.php resides. Cheers.

Comment: Both files are in the root folder - same level, C:\wamp\www\shops

Comment: @AliElMenini, ok, kindly try my edited rules once and let me know then, make sure htaccess is in www folder please(NOT inside shops).